# Efficient algorithm to look for cells equal to zero in matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix that looks like this one:

[image]

It has some cells with zero values and some others with different integer numbers. I want to select the cells that contain zeros in the way that the above image shows: only one zero-cell per row and column.

I mean, a valid solution for the previous matrix is shown using the coloured cells. For each cell selected, any of them is in a different row or column as another.

Given any matrix which has enough zero-cells for building this selection, is there any efficient algorithm that would find a valid solution? The problem is not as trivial as it seems and I want to implement the algorithm in R code.

The expected output should be the coordinates of the selected and valid zero-cells in the matrix given as an argument.

Comment: I edited the question to add that information. @RonakShah

Comment: It is a combinatorial problem: *brute force* or *backtracking* are usual concepts to solve such problems. Depending on the data you can reduce the problem, e.g. in your example the element in the last column is clear.